# C# List sorting with multiple range

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list containing multiple values in the range [-1, 1] and I want to sort them from 0 to 1 then from 0 to -1.

> Ex: 0.0, 0.25, 0.9, 1.0, -0.1, -0.24, -0.85

How could I do that, maybe using IComparable ? I would like to avoid using LINQ.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Linq? Also, `-85` is in your list, where would that come?

Comment: So you need to check if a value is negative and then sort by absolute value?

Comment: And where does zero go?

Comment: [Sorting a List<T> with IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx), but unless you just like pain then use LINQ...

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the Sort overload accepting a `Comparison`.
This should work:

```
public static int MyCompare(double x, double y)
{
    if (x >= 0.0 == y>=0.0)
        // same sign, compare by absolute value
        return Math.Abs(x).CompareTo(Math.Abs(y));

    if (x < 0.0)
        return 1;

    return -1;
}
```

usage:

```
var list = new List<double>();
// fill your list
// call sort using the Comparison

// hard syntax
//list.Sort((x,y) => MyCompare(x, y));

// easy syntax :)
list.Sort(MyCompare);

foreach (var x in list)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

see it at work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/odOJYh

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ way is to just do this (assuming you want to end up with a sorted array, the `ToArray` bit isn't needed):

```
var sorted = values.OrderBy( value => value < 0 ).ThenBy( Math.Abs ).ToArray();
```

The only reason I'm showing that is so you have can compare it with the non-LINQ approach using a comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<double>
{
    public int Compare( double x, double y )
    {
        if( x < 0 )
        {
            if( y >= 0 ) return 1;
            return -x.CompareTo( y );
        }
        else
        {
            if( y < 0 ) return -1;
            return x.CompareTo( y );
        }
    }

    public static MyComparer Instance{ get; } = new MyComparer();

    private MyComparer() {}
}
```

And then to use it:

```
Array.Sort( values, MyComparer.Instance);
```

The point is it's a lot more code (and many more places to mess up the comparison).  This also sorts the array in place (where the LINQ version will make a copy if you ask it to).